# Webpack - Why CommonJS is used by default?

Tags: webpack

Why require() in my js files always works even if I don't use a transpiler?

Why webpack will use CommonJS by default even outside the config file?

I want to use only ES6 modules syntax, and then I want that only import will be available in my js files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

webpack process require calls out of the box, it is a default behavior.
But you can disable this in your config file:

```
module.exports = {
    //...
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                //...
                parser: {
                    commonjs: false, // disable CommonJS
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#rule-parser